# What are the pros and cons of each way to initialize an expression?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

This is inspired from a [post](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/1m1izv/goingnative_2013_writing_quick_code_in_c_quickly/cc4ww2x) by Andrei Alexandrescu.

What are the pro's and con's of initializing an expression with the following methods? When should I prefer one over the other?

```
auto v = expr;
T v = expr;
auto v(expr);
T v(expr);
auto v { expr }; 
T v {expr};
```

Comment: Whenever it's easier to read. E.g. `auto p = std::make_shared<Foo>(1, 2, 3);`. Anytime a descriptive function returns something obvious that's hard to type - iterators, reference wrappers, weak-pointer locks, etc.

Comment: All depends on `T` and `expr`. e.g. If `T` is `int` I will not using `auto`.

Comment: @KerrekSB right but some of the C++ gurus agreed one of the ugliest syntax wise above is more preferable , specifically `auto v { expr }; ` I want to know why

Comment: @pyCthon: Matter of taste? The problem is of course that `T x(U())` is a function declaration, so `T x { expr }` is safer advice. Ditto for not requiring implicit copy constructors. I'd still say it's uglier than the "usual" syntax.

Comment: A personal preference for the new syntax: `if (auto fp = std::unique_ptr<FILE, int(*)(FILE*)>(std::fopen(filename, "rb"), std::fclose)) { /* process fp.get() */ }`

Comment: `auto v{expr}` is nearly always wrong; it gives you a `std::initializer_list<T>` not a `T`.

Comment: it depends on the compiler, how good the optimization is - otherwise readability

Comment: @Simple: [Alexandrescu said it was the best way](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/1m1izv/goingnative_2013_writing_quick_code_in_c_quickly/cc4ww2x)

Comment: @JanusTroelsen he's wrong.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
auto v = expr;
auto v(expr);
```

When in your code either you don't know the type of `expr` and want to stay generic, or in your code it is absolutely clear what type `expr` has (definition right at the line above, etc), so that the `auto` will not add confusion.

The form of the initialization, parens or not, is irrelevant (only relevant to language lawyers, as there are subtle differences). Use what you feel more comfortable with.

---

```
T v = expr;
T v(expr);
```

If in your code it is not clear what `expr` is (definition too far apart, etc..), or if you don't know the type of `expr` but want `v` to be of the type `T`. Use the first form if you want to keep working with the "kind of value" that "expr" has (i.e if `expr` is a string and `T` is of a string type). If you build up a whole new kind of value (i.e a `Widget`, and `expr` is the widget's color), use the second form.

---

```
auto v { expr };
```

Never use this in current C++ (and probably within the next few years). It will declare `v` to be an `std::initializer_list<TypeOfExpr>`. If you want that, use the type directly and write it out. It is way too subtle (and there are proposals for beyond-C++14 to change this fact, so there is hope that you can write this in C++17 or something like that).

---

```
T v {expr};
```

If you want to protect yourself from narrowing conversions (i.e going from `1000` to `char` accidentally), or if you want to initialize a class that has an initializer list constructor, or if you have an aggregate the member(s) of which you want to initialize, use this form. Alternatively, you may use the following if you are dealing with an initializer list constructor, an aggregate or simple non-class type

```
T v = { expr };
```

I would *not* use it for calling an arbitrary constructor. I would use the following form for that

```
T v(expr);
```

However, there are people who prefer to use the braces form for that too. I like to know for sure what my code is doing, hence when I want to call a constructor, and don't want to randomly do an aggregate or list initialization constructor call instead, I use parens instead of braces.

Comment: +1 for a good discussion. Though I wonder why not to default to `T v{expr}` for construction, after all, this is meant to be the "uniform" style. I see your point in wanting to trigger alternate construction methods explicitly, but do you think we'll move over to the `{}` style in the long run?

Comment: @MatthiasVallentin because of things like http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d64a2752a07dc380, I dislike list initialization. For my taste, there are just too many special cases, and when people say "T t(T()); is ambiguous, therefor list initialization is preferred" I can only laugh and point to the whole bag of semantic user-level ambiguity of list initialization.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb the sample code you posted returned 01 by g++4.8, instead of 21 by clang++.  I have 2 questions: 1. Is g++'s behavior correct?  I assumes so.  2. What's mechanics of A a2 = {a,1}; Does it call the constructor of A, then initialize b to 1?

Comment: @CandyChiu GCC's behavior is wrong according to the Standard. I recommend that you open a new questio about my sample code if you have doubts about the exact meaning.

Comment: If you *actually* want an l-value `initializer_list`, you must use the "`auto x{whatever}`" syntax. The public class interface of `initializer_list` gives no way of entering values. The only non-`auto` ways of entering values are the r-value built-in methods.

Answer (score 5):

`auto v = expr; T v = expr;` is just fine, but in the auto version it might be hard to understand the type of `expr`.

For example, in `auto x = snafuscate();`, what is the type of `x`??

In the presence of ambiguity, it's better to explicitly declare the type of the right hand side as: `auto x = Gadget { snafuscate() };`

...

`auto v(expr);` and `T v(expr);` are a bad idea, because a valid `expr` can also be understood as a function pointer.

This code does not compile:

```
int main()
{
    int x(int());
    return x + 3;
}

prog.cpp:4:11: error: invalid conversion from ‘int (*)(int (*)())’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
return x + 3;
         ^
```

...

`auto v { expr };` is almost always wrong because v's type becomes initializer_list instead of T.

See for best practices on auto: http://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/

Comment: `auto v{expr}` is nearly always wrong; it gives you a `std::initializer_list<T>` not a `T`.

Comment: This is very interesting, Herb Sutter and Andrei apparently had the opposite opinion, in that
`auto v { expr }`  is in fact the best way of the choices.

Comment: @pyCthon I don't think many people do know about this trap. I've seen people demonstrating the new C++14 generalised captures in lambdas write `[x{std::move(x)}](){ ... }` which *also* does the wrong thing.

Comment: Sorry for my english, what snafuscate stands for?

Comment: It's a funny-sounding word with no meaning, used for code examples

Answer (score 5):

Aside from cases where the meaning is different (e.g. `vector<int> v(12)` doesn't give you a vector with the value 12 in it), the compiler should give you the same thing for all of the above, and it's really just personal preference that dictates which is "better".

`auto` is useful when the type is difficult to type, and the type is clear from the context. But `auto x = 12;` is hard to tell if it's signed or unsigned, for example [I don't know the rules, probably signed].

Comment: `auto x = 12;` is `signed int`, `auto x = 12u;` is `unsigned int`

Comment: @xlc: And `auto y = 123456789876`? `auto z = 0x1234`?  :-)

Comment: `y` will be `long` on LP64 platforms, `long long` on LLP64. `z` is `unsigned int`. Perhaps I know the rules a little too well. @KerrekSB

Comment: auto x = 0x0f; // int

auto x2 = 0xff;  // int

auto x3 = 0xfffffff; //7 fs int

auto y = 0xffffffff ; // 8 fs  unsigned int

auto z = 0xfffffffff; // 9 fs  long long

auto t = 0xffffffffffffffff; // 16 fs unsigned long long

Comment: @bames53 What, hexadecimals are unsigned? Has this always been the case or is this new since 11/14?

Comment: @ChristianRau they're normally signed but if they don't fit in the range for the signed integer but do fit in the range for unsigned they are unsigned. For instance, `0x1234` is `signed int` but `0xFFFFFFFF` will typically be `unsigned int` not `signed long`.

Comment: This is in contrast to decimal literals which are always signed. For instance `4294967295` will never be `unsigned int` on common platforms. On 32-bit Linux and Windows it will be `signed long long` and on 64-bit Linux I believe its `signed long` (because `long` is 64-bits rather than 32 and `long` has a lower rank than `long long`). Conclusion: integer literals are a minefield; don't use them with `auto`.

Comment: @Simple That's what I also thought (and is also the behaviour of normal integer literals, no?), yet *bames53* claimed that `z` from *Kerrek*'s comment was an `unsigned int`.

Comment: @ChristianRau as I said in the next comment which you may have missed, decimal literals are never unsigned unless you suffix them with `U`. bames53 used the example of `0x1234` being `unsigned int` which is actually *never* true because `int` is guaranteed to be able to represent numbers up to `0x7FFF`.

Comment: @bames53: Hehe, well, I know where to *look up* the rules, but I know that they are a little complex :-)

Comment: @Simple Yeah, you're right, finally looked it up. So *bames53* was indeed wrong with his comment.

Comment: @ChristianRau Aw, I guess I didn't know the rules as well as I thought. The way I remembered it hex and oct literals were always unsigned, but I see now that's only with the `u` suffix.

Answer (score 2):

I think, needn't use auto as

```
auto x = 12332; // or
auto z = 0xffff; //
```

Because,

```
auto x = 12332; // type is  'int'
auto x2 = 0xffff // type is 'int'
auto y = 0xffffffff; // 8 fs,  type is unsigned int
auto z = 0xfffffffff;// 9 fs,  type is long long
auto t = 0xffffffffffffffff; // 16 fs, type is unsigned long long.
```

But, you can use

```
auto size = array.size();
```

Answer (score 2):

This is quite a difficult question.

There are two different issues.

The first is whether to use type deduction or not, that is to use the `auto` specifier or explicitly specify the type.  In general I would say it is better to explicitly specify the type to help with readability, except if the type is long and cumbersome (for example iterators):

```
auto it = vec.begin();
```

or if the type is obvious from the initializer:

```
auto pfoo = new Foo(x,y,z);
```

or if you don't care about readability.

The second is what type of initialization to use.  There is direct-initialization, copy-initialization and list-initialization - and the behaviour of initialization depends heavily on the type of the destination.  The differences between these are described in section 8.5 of the C++ standard.  Also initialization comes up in more places than just simple declarations.  Intialization takes place in parameter passing, return values, sub-expressions, statement conditions, array bounds, and many many other places.  It's really something that you need to understand the details of and some short summary isn't going to cut it.